# Flatten JSON data with jq

Tags: jq

I have output brakeman scan results to a json file and want to flatten the structure.

Brakeman json output sample looks like this

```json
{
    "scan_info": {
      "security_warnings": 9,
      "start_time": "2021-11-01 14:44:58 +1100",
      "end_time": "2021-11-01 14:45:13 +1100",
      "brakeman_version": "5.1.2"
    },
    "warnings": [
      {
        "warning_type": "Redirect",
        "warning_code": 18,
        "fingerprint": "cae2f2cfd8",
        "check_name": "Redirect",
        "message": "Possible unprotected redirect",
        "file": "app/controllers/my/controller.rb",
        "line": 24,
        "link": "https://brakemanscanner.org/docs/warning_types/redirect/",
        "code": "redirect_to....",
        "render_path": null,
        "location": {
          "type": "method",
          "class": "My::Controller",
          "method": "request_token"
        },
        "user_input": "my.base_url",
        "confidence": "High"
      },
      {.....}
    ],
    "ignored_warnings": [],
    "errors": [],
    "obsolete": ["xxx","yyyy"]
  }
```

I want to flatten the output into an array of objects similar to this. I want most data from the `warnings` array except `.location` and `.render_path`.

```json
[
{
  "brakeman_version": "5.1.2",
  "warning_type": "Redirect",
  "warning_code": 18,
  "fingerprint": "cae2f0d2cfd8",
  "check_name": "Redirect",
  "message": "Possible unprotected redirect",
  "line": 24,
  "link": "https://brakemanscanner.org/docs/warning_types/redirect/",
  "code": "redirect_to...",
  "confidence": "High"
 },
 {
  "brakeman_version": "5.1.2",
  "warning_type": "SQL Injection",
  "check_name": "SQL",
  "message": "Possible SQL injection",
  "warning_code": 35,
  ....
  "confidence": "High"
  }
]
```

Something like this gives a nested object for each item in the `warnings` array but I'd like to move them up a level
`jq '{brakeman_version: .scan_info.brakeman_version, start_time: .scan_info.start_time, warnings: .warnings[]}' ./brakeman.json`

Result

```json
{
  "brakeman_version": "5.1.2",
  "start_time": "2021-11-01 14:44:58 +1100",
  "warnings": {
    "warning_type": "Redirect",
    "warning_code": 18,
    "fingerprint": "xxxx",
    "check_name": "Redirect",
    "message": "Possible unprotected redirect",
    "line": 24,
    "link": "https://brakemanscanner.org/docs/warning_types/redirect/",
    "confidence": "High"
  },
  {...}
}
```

Something like this flattens the `.scan_info` part similarly but still leaves me with an array for `warnings` which is what was there in the first place.

```sh
jq '{
rails_version: .scan_info.rails_version,
security_warnings: .scan_info.security_warnings,
start_time: .scan_info.start_time,
brakeman_version: .scan_info.brakeman_version,
warnings: [.warnings[] | {warning_type: .warning_type,
warning_code: .warning_code,
fingerprint: .fingerprint,
check_name: .check_name,
confidence: .confidence} ],
obsolete: (.obsolete | join(",")),
}' ./brakeman.json
```

Results

```json
{
  "rails_version": "6.1.4.1",
  "security_warnings": 9,
  "start_time": "2021-11-01 14:44:58 +1100",
  "warnings": [
    {
      "warning_type": "SQL Injection",
      "warning_code": 0,
      "fingerprint": "xx",
      "check_name": "SQL",
      "message": "Possible SQL injection",
      "line": 178,
      "link": "https://brakemanscanner.org/docs/warning_types/sql_injection/",
      "confidence": "Medium"
    },
    {
      "warning_type": "Format Validation",
      "warning_code": 30,
      "fingerprint": "xxx",
      "check_name": "ValidationRegex",
      "line": 92,
      "link": "https://brakemanscanner.org/docs/warning_types/format_validation/",
      "code": null,
      "user_input": null,
      "confidence": "High"
    },
  ]
}
```

Using jq how do I correctly flatten the structure to output as desired?

I've tried some suggestions found on SO like

```
jq '{
rails_version: .scan_info.rails_version,
brakeman_version: .scan_info.brakeman_version,
.warnings[] as $in | $in | del(.location, .render_path) as $in2 | $in2,
obsolete: (.obsolete | join(",")),
}' ./brakeman.json
```

but have been going around in circles at this stage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With assumptions based on your description provided, I guess you are looking to do this

```
.scan_info + ( .warnings[] | del(.location, .render_path) )
```

If you want the entire results packed into an array, enclose the above filter within square brackets(`[ ]`)

[jqplay demo](https://jqplay.org/s/qnmh1qTPPw)